# phpunit coverage with phpdbg: uncovered case lines on switch statement

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

We have a problem with coverage on functions with swtich statement:

[image]

```
PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2019 20:47:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.7, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.7, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

PHPUnit 7.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Also, I try with PHPUnit 8, but the problem persists.

CLARIFICATION: This is a problem using php+phpdbg, not XDebug. There is a lot of questions and possible solutions, but for PHP+XDebug.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not use PHPDBG for code coverage. Use PCOV oder Xdebug instead.

Comment: wow! it's an honor a comment from you Sebastian. Some time ago I migrate from Xdebug to PHPDBG, because XDebug takes double time than phpdbg. I'm testing PCOV now, very cool, but is not avaiable yet on Nanobox and we have some projects with this orchestrator; maybe a temporary solution is pcov-clobber. Thanks a lot for your time and work.